# Electric warning signs question

Tags: electricity, soft-question, electric-current, voltage

I've always wandered why do the warning signs show the voltage, not the current. I mean, it's the current that kills you.

Comment: Visit a plant for alkali electrolysis or where Acheson graphite or silicon carbide is produced. In spite of many thousands of amperes applied to the cells, there are only danger signs for magnetic field as you may know from NMR apparatus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Higher voltages allow conduction paths that can do less than kill. You can get serious electrical burns and even arcs that pass through the body and leave burn channels, as in lightning strikes, or sitting on a charged laser capacitor (fatal for a Stanford grad student many years ago). Nerve damage and permanent heart arrhythmia can result. Might be good for depression. Enough voltage and your clothes or shoes won't be a protection and once get get some ions moving, in tissue or an arc in air, the current can go way up.

If you had to pick the most lethal device around undergrad labs it would have to be the constant power source used in electrophoresis. It will automatically increase voltage as much as needed to get enough current to meet the constant power setting. A real good student eliminator when people remove the protective covers and switches. Second is probably old X-ray diffraction equipment in geology and/or old electron microscopes where either can have worn high voltage cables. The common auto-transformer or Variac is always "hot", even if turned off when the wall plug is in the wrong way. I don't know why they are not responsible for more accidents. Old ones have plugs that fit either way in new sockets.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the current that kills, but it is voltage that is necessary to make the current flow through your body, which is the thing that we usually need warnings about.

If there is 1MW of electricity flowing through a superconducting wire at 1V difference from ground, that is a crazy amount of amps, but if you touch it, you will not get 1MA of current flowing through you. Your body has a resistance that can only be overcome by a voltage. At 1V difference from ground, only mAs will flow through your body, the rest will stay in the wire.

The bigger risk from such a high current would be the magnetic field that it would create which could rip any jewellery from your body. In cases like this, there are signs which warn about the dangerous magnetic field.

Comment: Fun fact: If you could touch that superconducting wire (which you probably can't due to the liquid helium shell), you would immediately heat it up above the critical temperature, making it quench. The 1MA of current flowing through the now non-zero resistance material would vaporize it in an explosive manner, killing you. Shortly before that, you would also get blisters on your finger. ...Hate blisters.

Comment: @DerManu I'm looking forward to the CT scanner warning signs being updated to: Danger, Damaging equipment can cause blisters on your fingers!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is power that kills.  A human body presents variable resistance depending on how good an electrical contact you make with the hot terminals.  If you are wearing rubber sneakers, for instance, then you provide a high resistance making it "safe" to touch a hot 120 Vpp wire with one hand.  (Don't do that please!  This is in no way an invitation or statement that it is safe to touch a hot 120 Vpp wire.)  On the other hand, if you grabbed one of the two wires from an American 120 Vpp socket with each hand, you would provide a low resistance path which would allow the current to travel through your heart and kill you.  However, with a 1 V battery, even if it were able to supply 100 A of current, the intrinsic human body resistance from one hand to the other is on the order of 10 kOhms with dry hands.  This could never kill you even if you provided direct contact, delivering about 1/10 of a mW.  (Say, 1 mW with wet hands, and I suppose I should say don't pick up any hot electrodes with wet or dry hands under any conditions, just to be safe.)

Therefore, if you had a sign warning of a 100 A source, you wouldn't know if that was 100 A that could only be delivered at 1 V, and therefore harmless, or 100 A delivered at 12 V which could possibly be lethal on a bad day, or 100 A delivered at 1000 V which would be certainly lethal on any day.